# Why do REST verbs not necessarily correspond to CRUD actions?

Tags: rest, http, architecture, domain-driven-design, crud

I sat in a talk from [Eric Evans](https://domainlanguage.com/ddd/) (author of [Domain Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)) and he made the point that it was a confusion of REST to assume that the four REST actions automatically mapped to the four CRUD actions. ie

```
POST   x=> Create
GET    x=> Read
PUT    x=> Update
DELETE x=> Delete
```

I kind of missed his reasoning. Something about the architectural concerns being different.

My question is: **Why do REST actions not correspond to CRUD actions?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Because of Idempotence

POST and PUT can both be used for "create" and "update" operations. The difference between POST and PUT is idempotence: **PUT is idempotent, while POST is not.**

> Idempotence is the property of certain operations ..., that can be applied multiple times without changing the result beyond the initial application.
>
> - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence)

This means that in order to comply with the HTTP specification, you must use PUT for idempotent operations and POST for non-idempotent ones. This is specified in [RFC7231 section 4.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2).

Note that idempotence is described by the HTTP standard and has nothing to do with REST directly.

### Example

Understanding idempotence is easy with an example. Let's take a create operation on a REST API that should create a "customer" resource. The idempotent variant would look as follows:

```
PUT /customers/cust42
{ "name": "John Doe" }
```

This creates the customer with name "John Doe" with the ID "cust42". The important part here is that **the client specifies the ID**. If the client issues the same PUT request again, no new resource will be created - the operation is idempotent.

With POST, on the other hand, the request would look as follows:

```
POST /customers
{ "name": "John Doe" }
```

The server determines the ID and creates a customer resource with name "John Doe". This operation is *not* idempotent, because issuing the same POST again would create a *second* user resource.

**So choosing between POST or PUT is not a question of "create" vs "update". The above examples both create a resource, but one does so in an idempotent manner (PUT) and the other not (POST).**

#### Relation to DDD

In DDD, the goal is to create a language around your domain problem in a way that is meaningful to the domain (and their experts). Naming everything after CRUD is thus generally a bad idea.

The above guidance is still useful, for DDD, however. If you have state-changing API operation on your DDD application that is idempotent, you use PUT, otherwise you use POST. See the answer of Guillaume31 for some good domain-oriented examples of DELETE.

Answer (score 4):

> Why do REST actions not correspond to CRUD actions?

Because otherwise it would mean that applications with a rich domain (i.e. not CRUD) cannot be accessed through a REST interface.

An HTTP verb alone isn't enough to describe a domain action. But combined with a URI, a content type and situated within an overarching Domain Application Protocol, you can have a mapping from the HTTP world to the realm of domain commands that makes sense.

DELETE can thus translate to different things in different circumstances : Remove, Erase, Archive, Deny, Cancel, Conclude (a process/ a transaction), etc.

Comment: This should be accepted. Idempotence is valid too, but this is much more important by REST.

Answer (score 0):

A common misconcept that REST resources map to domain entities and HTTP methods map to operations on these domain entities. In some cases this can be true, but in those cases (simple CRUD without business logic) nobody would use DDD.

Just to clarify we are talking about HTTP methods here and not "REST actions". REST uses standards to build the uniform interface between the client and the service, and HTTP is one of such standards. If you take the time to read about HTTP methods here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html , then you will realize, that there is no 1:1 mapping between CRUD and PGPD. theDmi already mentioned idempotence, but for example you can use POST to send search queries as well, which is certainly not "create".

As guillaume31 wrote REST is not RPC. You map the possible operations to the URI, HTTP method, and other request meta data, and not just to the HTTP method. For example you can map a `beginTransaction()` operation to a `POST /transactions/` hyperlink or a `wishHerHappyBirthday()` operation to a `POST /greetings/ {subject: "her", occasion: "birthday"}` hyperlink. It is easier and faster to route based on the HTTP method and the URI, but that is not mandatory, you can use any HTTP header and the body as well if you want.